# Stock Phone app doesn't work in split-window mode on Android Nougat

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, phone-app

I have Wiko U Pulse Lite running on Android 7.0 Nougat. I would like to use Google Keep or Google Drive in split-window mode with the Phone application. This is because every time I perform a banking operation, I need to copy numbers and passwords from one window to the other, otherwise I need to recur to open and paper to use as my buffer for storing these data.

Is there a reason why the Phone application with its dialer keypad won't work in split-window mode? Is this fixed in later version of Google's Android OS?

Comment: It works in Oreo in OnePlus 6, but the implementation of stock phone app can vary. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR6fw.jpg // In which Android phone did you have that issue with split screen mode with phone app?

Comment: I have a Wiko U PULSE Lite.

Comment: A possible workaround is to try 3rd-party dialer (try [Google's own app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer)?) and check if this also happens on all Phone apps (which I somehow doubt), or only on Wiko's stock Phone app.

Comment: Thanks but I get an error message saying my device is not compatible with this app when I open the page in the play store. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For an app to be allowed [to work in split-window mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#configuring), there is a certain parameter `android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]` that has to be set to `true`.

Since Android 7.0, this is `true` by default, but it's still possible to be set to `false` if the developer thinks the app will not behave correctly in split-window.

As @Andrew T. suggested in a comment, all you can do as a user is to find another phone app that allows split-window.

Answer (score 1):

If Developer options is enable, you can set "Force activities to be resizable" to On.

Settings -> Developers options -> Force activities to be resizable

Then, restarts the phone.
It has worked for me when there were apps not developed to use split screen by default.